# Yammer share button not firing with single click

Tags: yammer

I am trying to integrate Yammer share button https://developer.yammer.com/docs/share-button, I successfully implemented as instructed, but the only catch is first time it requires two click to fire up, later on single click seems to do the job. Here is the code below.

```js
function clickSaveShare(){
  var options = {
    customButton : true, //false by default. Pass true if you are providing your own button to trigger the share popup
    classSelector: 'homeBtn',//if customButton is true, you must pass the css class name of your button (so we can bind the click event for you)
    defaultMessage: 'My custom Message', //optionally pass a message to prepopulate your post
    pageUrl: 'www.microsoft.com' //current browser url is used by default. You can pass your own url if you want to generate the OG object from a different URL.
  }; 
 yam.platform.yammerShare(options);
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<span href="#" class="homeBtn" onclick="clickSaveShare(339,'Reverse KT')"> Click here to share</a>

<script>

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s0.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_social_buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">yam.platform.yammerShare();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling `yam.platform.yammerShare()` doesn't actually call the share to Yammer function despite its name. What it does is apply a click event to the specified DOM element so that when that element is clicked the Yammer popup will appear.

The reason you have to click the button twice is that the first time `clickSaveShare` is called, it calls `yam.platform.yammerShare()` which sets up a click event on the specified DOM element. The next time the button is clicked your click event has been replaced with the Yammer one so it works as expected.

One simple way to fix it given that you are including jQuery would be to use jQuery's document.ready event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var options = {
    customButton : true,
    classSelector: 'homeBtn',
    defaultMessage: 'My custom Message',
    pageUrl: 'www.microsoft.com'
  };

 yam.platform.yammerShare(options);
});
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/timcollins1/pen/pZNJYe) is a CodePen example of the above.